# Access the calling file name from within a function in a different file

Tags: file, import, deno

I'm looking to have a function that has access the path string of the calling file

`util.ts`

```
const util = (meta) => {
  console.log(meta.url)
}
```

I have this file that uses it

`example.ts`

```
util(import.meta) // logs ...example.ts
```

Is it possible to do this without passing `import.meta`?

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to do this without passing import.meta?

Yes, you can use `Error` and parse the stack trace.

```js
export const metaUrl = () => {
  const error = new Error()
  const lines = error.stack?.split('\n')
  let line = lines && lines[3] || ''
  line = line.replace('at', '')
  line = line.replace(/\:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+/, '')
  return line.trim()
}
```

Comment: oof, hacky but interesting