# How to export for specific files in nodejs or deno

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, deno

By using `export` keyword, we can export anything from a file to another file in JavaScript. But is their any way to export for specific files. So that other file can't import from this file.

```js
export const t = {
a:'this will export for index.js only'
}
```

Comment: No, there is no way.

Comment: As @jabaa [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76844153/how-to-export-for-specific-files-in-nodejs-or-deno#comment135471099_76844153): that’s not possible. However, if you edit the question to explain to us what the real problem is that you think would be solved by such a mechanism, perhaps as can offer ideas or answers to solve the real problem.

Comment: @jsejcksn Actually I want to export some private data as an object or function and want to create a bound where without access no one can read that object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to how java controls access of classes to the rest of the application `public, private, protected` then no. If you only want a singular file to be able to use a variable then declare the variable in the file you want to use. or look into changing the architecture of your application. Ex: change your function to use dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to achieve that directly, since `import.meta` does not contain that information. But you can do it if you export a factory function instead, that way you can access the caller file by using `Error.stack`.

**module.js**

```js
const callerUrl = () => {
  const error = new Error()
  const lines = error.stack?.split('\n')
  let line = lines && lines[3] || ''
  line = line.replace('at', '')
  line = line.replace(/\:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+/, '')
  return line.trim()
}

export default () => {
  const file = callerUrl();
  const x = {};

  if(file.endsWith('/index.js')) {
    x.a = 'from index.js'
  }
  else if(file.endsWith('/foo.js')) {
    x.a = 'from foo.js'
  }

  return x;
}
```

**index.js**

```
import factory from './module.js';
import './foo.js';

console.log(factory());
// { a: "from index.js" }
```

See: [Access the calling file name from within a function in a different file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74425297/access-the-calling-file-name-from-within-a-function-in-a-different-file/74429547#74429547)

---

I don't recommend exporting something based on the caller file though.

Comment: The `Error` constructor can be intercepted to change `stack` thereby bypassing a stack inspecting guard. e.g. `globalThis.Error = new Proxy(globalThis.Error, { construct(...args) { const result = Reflect.construct(...args); result.stack = "42"; return result; } }); ` will cause all new `Error` instances to have a ` stack` value of `"42"`.

Comment: @mfulton26 What does that have to do with the answer? You can intercept a lot of things in JS, don't intercept it if you want to use this approach, and don't use anything intercepting Error constructor. 

You could comment on any JS answer using any method that can be intercepted. "Don't use `.map`, it can be intercepted, "Don't use `.endsWith`, it can be intercepted"

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that checking the stack trace doesn't solve the problem, it only creates a hurdle for someone to get access to what they want. If the factory method doesn't return what someone wants then all they need to do to get what they want out of the factory is to slip a different `stack` value in and now they've imported something that was intended to not be importable by them.

Comment: FYI: I didn't down vote your answer. I appreciate the "thinking out of the box" solution. I've explored `import.meta.resolve()` along with some other APIs but ultimately I don't think there's a way to do what's being asked.

Comment: Never, in any of my applications Error stack was modified, so I don't think it is a real problem, you're creating imaginary scenarios. Don't rely on any property or method since it can be intercepted, use assembly instead.

Comment: Hi @MarcosCasagrande! I don't downvote cavalierly (and as you pointed out, it costs the actor rep to do so), but downvoting is just as important as upvoting to manage quality on this site. I'm curious — what is your meaning of "always"?

Comment: Why I downvoted this answer: the error [`stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack) property is not in the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-error-objects) which means that it's non-standard and is not on a standards track — so any code which relies on it will be subject to varying values in different runtime implementations and breaking changes in each runtime's implementation. AFAIK, none of them claim any guarantee of a specific format — please inform me if I'm mistaken.